# alternate series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, alternating-expression

I am studying calculus, and now I got some practice from my lecture
which is as follows.

Decide whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{({-1})^n}{(n-1)}$ is convergent, divergent, absolute convergent, or conditionally convergent.

Before using some method, I noticed that this series will have a term $\frac{1}{0}$ as its first term.

What should I do with this term?
Should I ignore this term and go on with all test methods like alternating series test or ratio test and so on? Or I have to do something first with that term before moving to another method?

Comment: Ask your instructor. The first term means that the sum is undefined, but presumably they means $n=2$ as the starting index.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,
but in general situation
is there any convention, theorem an so on that teach us what to do when we meet a series that has undifined term?

Comment: Nothing general, it is just undefined. Since the purpose here is presumably for you to apply the alternating series test then the $n=1$ can be ignored, but I would either ask the instructor or at least comment on it in the answer sheet.

Comment: aah i see, thanks for the advice and have a nice day!

Comment: If this was a question on a test, and I wasn't permitted to ask for an explanation on the $~\dfrac{1}{0}~$ term, then I (also) would respond that the entire series is undefined because it has at least one undefined term.